# Factory Pattern of IOC, always need to instantiate?

Tags: c#, factory, factory-pattern

I'd like my app to be not strictly tied to an IOC, so basically my application should need to call an IOC factory pattern that solve the specific implementation on runtime.

So, first off I've created my interface:

**IIOCService**

```
interface IIOCService
{
    void RegisterSingleton<RegisterType>()
        where RegisterType : class;

    void RegisterMultiple<RegisterType>()
        where RegisterType : class;

    void RegisterMultiple<RegisterType>(IEnumerable<Type> implementationTypes);

    // and so on
}
```

then an implementation of IIOCService, using **TinyIOC**

```
class TinyIOCServiceImpl : IIOCService
{
    private static readonly TinyIOCServiceImpl _Current = new TinyIOCServiceImpl();

    public static TinyIOCServiceImpl Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _Current;
        }
    }

    TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container;

    public TinyIOCServiceImpl()
    {
        container = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current;
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<RegisterType>()
        where RegisterType : class
    {
        container.Register(typeof(RegisterType)).AsSingleton();
    }

    // ...and so on
}
```

For the class that decides to resolve the implementation of the IOC container, I've created an IOCFactory

**IOCFactory**

```
class IOCFactory
{
    public enum IOC { TinyIOC }

    public IIOCService GetService(IOC iocType)
    {
        switch (iocType)
        {
            case IOC.TinyIOC:
                return TinyIOCServiceImpl.Current;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Now my question is:

Should I need to reinstantiate the factory for every class where IOC is needed or there is some more elegant way?

```
IIOCService iocService = new IOCFactory().GetService(IOCFactory.IOC.TinyIOC); 
// code needed everytime I need to use IOC  (i.e. ServiceLocator, ViewModelLocator, etc.)
// is this code a bit redundant ???
```

Comment: So you're writing an IoC container for your IoC container? When does it stop? Your IoC/DI framework shouldn't hit that many aspects of your application anyway, so it shouldn't touch that much code, hence being fairly trivial to replace.

Comment: The general way I've seen it done is to instantiate container and register everything on [web]app startup and then store it as a property of a globally accessible construct.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that creating a wrapper around your IOC container is a bit redundant. But, if you need to call your IOC container to resolve a specific, on run-time determined, instance of an interface, you can create a resloving interface (not with the factory pattern, but staying within the IOC pattern). Something like this (this is too basic, just so you can get the idea):

```
public interface IResolve {
    public T Resolve<T>();
}
```

You can create an implementation for this specific interface and expose it to your IOC container. There is no issue doing this in a single instance pattern.

When you need to resolve something in a class that was resolved by the IOC container, just add the IResolve to your constructor and you can address the IOC container without a dependency on whatever brand of IOC container is used.

I hope this brought some clarity for you?

Comment: Uhm... I'm afraid of being misunderstood.
I'm NOT thinking of resolve the IOC implementation using IOC itself (yes it would be horrible and redundant), but in another way (i.e , hard-coded or using a property file)

Comment: So you would like your app to switch IOC container in runtime?

Comment: @Josh Verbies
at startup

Comment: Ok, i get it now. If I was you I would still use the above pattern to get a resolver, but I would make your switch in your application bootstrapper (where you will configure your IOC container). That way the logic for switching the IOC container is contained (pun intended) in only one location.

Comment: Yes, but there is also the ViewModelLocator implied.
So I thought it was a bit redundant to reinstantiate the Factory

Comment: To my opinion there is a lot redundant here, but if you use this factory pattern you might just as well make it a static class and use only one instance.